# mingw upgrade only gdb without changing gcc

Tags: gdb, upgrade, mingw32

I'd like to upgrade my mingw32 gdb from version 7.4 to 7.5 (see reason [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=458967)). Unfortunately the old gcc 4.6.2 can't be upgraded, because that's the latest tested version for our software (run into issues with 4.8.x). Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two programs are totally independent.  They share a bit of source code under the hood, but they are on different release schedules and their release tar files don't share anything.

So, there is nothing preventing upgrading gdb while keeping gcc the same -- just rebuild gdb but nothing else.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I'd prefer not to build from source (I guess there'll be gotchas on the way). Is there any alternative?

Comment: I simply took the latest gdb (7.6.1) from mingw32 and it seems to work.